# Method to change resource attribute based on nested resource attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested-attributes

I've got a Rails 4 app. Fairly simple question; I've written a method, but I don't know where it should go and how to call it.

I have a resource, `Goals`, and a nested resource, `Tasks` (ie. each goal has tasks). All that part works fine.

What I want to do is set it so that once the `status` of each `task` for a `goal` is true, the `status` of that `goal` changes to true.

The content of the method I'd like to use is:

```
completed = true
@goal.tasks.each do |t|
  if !t.status?
    completed = false
  end
end
if completed?
  @goal.status = true
end
```

which checks if all a `goal`'s tasks have `status`:true, and if so, changes the `status` of the `goal` to true as well.

My idea would be to put that method in the `Goal` model, but that's as far as I can guess.

- Where does the method go? (is it in the model like I thought?)
- How do I ( / do I need to) call the method?

(I'm aware the method might have a few minor syntax errors in it, but once I can actually use it, I'll be able to test and tweak it!)

Thanks to anybody taking the time to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your function as follows:

```
@goal.status = @goals.tasks.map(&:complete).all?
```

Assuming you want to know as soon as possible whether or not your `goal` is complete, you'll want to put this function in your `Task` model. You can do it as follows:

```
def Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :goal

  after_save :goal_completed

  def goal_completed
    if self.goal.tasks.map(&:completed).all?
      self.goal.update_attribute(:completed, true)
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, if you have a lot of `tasks` for one `goal`, this could get costly very quickly, since you're pulling all of a `goal`'s `tasks` every time a `task` is saved. So, for a larger database, I'd recommend keeping a count of completed tasks for each goal. (This is actually pretty similar to something I implemented in a project of mine.)

To start, you'll need to add a counter cache column in your `goals` for `tasks_count` (if you haven't already), and add another column to `goals` called `completed_tasks_count`, or something like that. Make sure they both default to zero.

```
def Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, inverse_of: :goal, counter_cache: true
end

def Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :goal, inverse_of: :tasks

  after_initial :set_completed_tasks_count, on: new
  around_save :goal_complete

  def set_completed_tasks_count
    self.completed = false if self.new_record? && self.completed.nil?
  end

  def goal_complete
    yield
    if self.completed? && !self.completed_was
      self.review.increment!(:completed_tasks_count)
    elsif (!self.completed? && self.completed_was) || self.marked_for_destruction?
      self.review.decrement!(:completed_tasks_count)
    end
  end
end
```

Hopefully this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, that's a much more comprehensive solution than what I'd thought of!